# Cannot flag an answer or pass the audit?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, review-audits

While reviewing "Late answers" queue, I came across this answer:

[image]

I thought of a "link only answer" and tried to check the post itself by clicking "link" but it was already deleted. So it should've been an audit, sure of my choice I clicked on "flag".

Then I got :

[image]

I don't have this post in my flag list (or at least this is not one waiting for a review).
Could this be a bug? [This is a link](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/19409547) to the review post.

Comment: I just passed the audit... Weird. Maybe you flagged this post before it was deleted?

Comment: You flagged it as VLQ on March 22nd - shortly afterwards it was deleted in review and your flag marked helpful.

Comment: Is it okay to click the link and check?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think you *did* flag the post after all in the past (edit: confirmed by a ♦), that's why the system doesn't allow you to flag again.

You can still pass the audit with downvoting the answer.

Comment: That explains ! Just did the downvote and passed the audit :)

Comment: `you don't encounter normal posts you've already voted or flagged in the First Posts, Late Answers` That is not exactly true. I already got several of them. But since the "I'm Done" button is clickable before you even did something, you can just move on.

Comment: @rollstuhlfahrer strange; on several smaller sites, where I see a sizable portion of *all* review items, it never occurred to me.

Comment: I second what @rollstuhlfahrer I've had many posts that I've flagged or voted on come up later in review. In the LQPRQ I was able to recommend deletion on a post that I flagged as NaA earlier that day.

Comment: OK, I removed that part since it's apparently untrue.